# Can't run or compile anything !!!! -> symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderC1Ev

Tags: ros, catkin-make, libroscpp, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it appears that there is an unknown symbol in the `libroscpp.so` file, and now catkin can find anything in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/` even though everything is there. No changes were made to the system that I can find, how did this happen and how do I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122161/can%27t-run-or-compile-anything-!!!!--%3E-symbol-lookup-error:-/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so:-undefined-symbol:-_zn3ros6headerc1ev/) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having the exact same problem then I found [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/120541/problem-of-running-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/).
My issue seems to have been caused by OS updates running across errors while updating the ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) with karma: 141 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1